# Encrypted DVDs Do Not Autoplay

Tags: encryption, dvd

I have installed Ubuntu Mate 15.04.

When I insert an audio CD or a non-commercial DVD into the drive a window will appear asking me what I want to do.  I know how to change the settings to cause the disk to automatically play with a particular program (e.g. VLC).

However, when I insert a encrypted DVD into the drive this window does not appear.

I am, however, able to open VLC and play the encrypted DVD without any problems so I am sure that all the software needed to actually play the DVD is installed.

There is a message in /var/log/syslog stating "Read of scrambled sector without authentication".

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I'm using Vivid (15.04)!

It seems that VLC is able to cope with this type of encryptions but not Ubuntu. BTW, the "undetectable" DVD plays and is being detected in Windows.

Have you found any solutions yet?

In the mean time, I'll look in other forums.